# Asserting a WPF Textbox' background color using Coded UI Test in VS2015

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I have a business rule under which the background color of a text box must change depending on the value in the text box. How can I assert that the background color of the text box is as expected in a Coded UI Test case in VS2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to do this is capturing an image of your UITestControl and asserting a specified pixel color:

```
//Capture an image of your test control
Bitmap testControlImage = yourUITestControl.CaptureImage() as Bitmap;

// Get the color of a pixel you specify within the captured image.
Color pixelColor = testControlImage.GetPixel(50, 50); 

// Assert the pixel color
Assert.AreEqual(pixelColor.ToString(), "Color [A=255, R=99, G=99, B=99]");
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I was not immediately able to compare with "known colors" such as Color.Orange, so I convert the acquired color to ARGB and mask the A out, retaining only the RGB values of the actual value. I then compare this with the RGB values of the known color, converted and masked values of the known color:

Comment: '            var backgroundColor = bitmap.GetPixel(6, 6).ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF;
            var compareColor = Color.Orange.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF;

Answer (score 1):

I've never found this to be possible when I've looked before so I've put it down to something that can't be done yet, but some people have had some success on other similar posts that might help you out: [Accessing font properties of wpftext control in codedUI testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811340/accessing-font-properties-of-wpftext-control-in-codedui-testing)